# How to make a script read a value from a property file and pass it to the same script?

Tags: bash

I am new to linux shell script. i want that my script read a property file and save the value in any variable , the same which i can pass in same script..
 as i wrote script is not fulfilling my requirement:

```
!/bin/bash

. test1

flat

if [ "$1" == test1 ]; then
    flat=$1;  /assign value to var flat
    echo "flat"        
fi
```

test1 is property file which includes :

```
la=12

tu=15
```

now i want when i run:

```
./myscript la
```

it read it from property file and store the value in flat variable.
Please help me.

Comment: If you want `flat` to have its value in the shell after `myscript` returns, you'll have to source it instead: `source ./myscript la` or `. ./myscript la`.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to use indirect referencing, but to do so, you need to store the value of the special parameter `$1` in a regular parameter first.

```
!/bin/bash

. test1

var="$1"

# Only assign to flat if the variable specified in var is defined
if [ -n "${!var:-}" ]; then
    flat="${!var}";  # assign value to var flat
    echo "flat"        
fi
```

---

First, `${!var}` expands to the value of the variable whose name is in `var`. If `var` is "foo", it's the same as `$foo`. If `var` is "baz", it's the same as `$baz`.

`${var:-default}` expands to the value of `var` if it is set and has a non-null value. Otherwise, it expands to whatever you have after the ':-', in this case the string default. If there is no string, it uses the null value. So `${var:-}` would expand to the null string if `var` was not set (or was already the null string).

Combining the two, `${!var:-}` takes the variable var, and uses its value as a variable name. It then tries to expand that variable, and if it isn't set or is null, expand to the null string. So if `var` is `la`, it expands to the value of `la`. If `var` is `re`, and there is no variable `re` set, it expands to the null string.

Finally, the `-n` operator tests if its argument is non-zero length. In other words, it checks that the result of trying to expand the variable whose name is in `var` is not the null string. If that's true, then expand it again (yes, it's a little redundant) and assign its value to `flat`.

As the answer is written above, the variable `flat` is undefined if the argument to the script is not the name of a variable set in `test1`. If you don't mind `flat` being set regardless (say, `flat=""`), you don't need the `if` statement. You can just use one line to set the value of `flat`:

```
#!/bin/bash
. test1
var="$1"
flat="${!var:-}"
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much ....it works......
if possible could you please explain me the statement:
if [ -n "${!var:-}" ]; then

what exactly it doing....it would be helpful to me ...
thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to accept the answer as correct when you get a chance.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly you want to achieve an indirect variable dereferencing (see e.g. [this example](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html)).

The solution is to use `eval`:

```
eval flat=\$$1
```

Comment: You can eliminate `eval`, which could be unsafe, with `var=$1; flat=${!var}`. (Imagine if the first parameter is "3 rm -rf /")

Comment: To be honest I don't see a big problem with your example. `flat` would get the content "3 rm -rf /".

Comment: It expands to "eval flat=\$3 rm -rf /". Now you're evaluating a simple command with `flat` in its environment. Try `foo () { eval flat=\$$1; }; foo "3 ls"`